# Argument 1 passed to App\Entity\User::setToken() must be an instance of App\Entity\Token or null, string given, called in

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to **update** a row in my database.

In this case i'm using two entities *User* and *Token*

This is my method in my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/forget-password/", name="forget", methods="GET|POST")
 */
 public function emailrestore(Request $request, UserRepository $userrepository, TokenGenerator $tokengenerator, MailGenerator $mailgenerator)
 {
    $userInfo = ['email' => null];
    $form = $this->createForm(ForgetPasswordType::class, $userInfo);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $userInfo = $form->getData();
        $email = $userInfo['email'];
        $user = $userrepository->findOneBy(['email' => $email]);
        if ($user === null){
            $message = "This email doesn't exist in our database or is wrong.";
            $this->session->getFlashBag()->add("danger", $message);
            return $this->redirectToRoute('forget');
        }
        // 2.5) Generating token
        $pledge = $tokengenerator->generateToken();
        $url = $this->generateUrl('recovery/', 
        array(
            'token' => $pledge
        ),
        UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
        );
        $user->setToken($pledge);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($token);
        $entityManager->flush();
        // 6) Sending the email to the user
        //$mailgenerator->registration($email, $url);
    }         
    return $this->render('emails/forget-password/forget-password.html.twig', array (
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
 }
```

As you can see in the part of dump($user); I have the following data through my request:

[image]

As i understand in this same part, near dump($user). I want update the new token form my user, with the method $token->setToken($pledge)

Which is the correct method in order to manage this?.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
...............
UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL
        );
        $token = $user->getToken();
        $creation = new \DateTime("now");
        $valid = (new \DateTime("now"))->modify('+1 day');
        $token->setToken($pledge);
        $token->setCreation($creation);
        $token->setValid($valid);
        $token->setActive(true);
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($token);
        $entityManager->flush();
................
```

It works as i expected, is this the correct way?.

Comment: Depending what do you need I suppose. From what I see I guess you want to give a `User` a generated `Token` when that `User` asks for password recovery, then send a link containing that `Token`'s value with an email to the `User`. You (plan to) use `Token`'s `$active` property to check whether it is still allowed to be used to change the `User`'s password. Is that somewhat the case?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some changes:

- instead of editing existing `Token`, generate a whole new entity each time. Keep in mind to set [orphan removal](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal) to delete the old `Token` if present
- persist the `$user`, not the `$token`. Keep the [owning side](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/unitofwork-associations.html) in mind
- in the `Token` entity itself there is no need to keep a `$active` field, since the entity itself seems to have an expiry date under `$valid`. I would change that name to `$validUntil` or so (so it indicated a date/time) and use it to check if the `Token` is indeed still active. You could modity the `Token` entity like so:

```php
private $validUntil;

public function isActive()
{
    return $this->validUntil > (new DateTime('now'));
}
```

- instead of validating the email inside the `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())`, I would add a [custom validation constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) that would check if the `User` with given email exists. This way, if there is no `User`, you never go pass the `$form->isValid()` part, and the error on `email` field is automatically appended to it, so there is no need for a flash message (unless you want it)

In a broader picture, I would also change the `Token` entity to have a `$user` property for the relation (instead of `$username`), and a `$value` property for the `Token`'s value (instead of `$token`). I would rename `$username` to `$user` in the `Profile` entity as well (and possibly in other entities with a relation to the `User`).